# chart is not getting updated from the values it received from Jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, chart.js

Use Case :
I am trying to populate my chart based on the data fetched by Jquery.

```
$.getJSON("/dashboard/", function(data, status)
        {

            var test_data=data
            console.log(test_data)
            chart.data.datasets[0].data=test_data;
            chart.update();
        }
```

output of  **console.log(test_data)**

```
 data: Array(3)
    0: 500
    1: 200
    2: 50
    length: 3
```

However this is not updating my chart .

Chart displays no values, without any error

[image: Output of above code]

When i hard code the value as shown below , the chart is getting updated.

```
$.getJSON("/dashboard/", function(data, status)
        {

            var test_data=data
            console.log(test_data)
            chart.data.datasets[0].data=[500,200,50];
            chart.update();
        }
```

After hard coded value
[image: After hard coded]
What is the trick i am missing here?

**Update**

The problem was that i was not using the response of Ajax in my fucntion, i have updated my code like below and it worked

```
$.getJSON("/dashboard/", function(response, status)
        {

            chart.data.datasets[0].data=response.data;
            chart.update();
        }
        )
```

Comment: Are any errors thrown? What does `dashboard` return when gotten? Do you need to parse it?

Comment: No errors ! ! i have attached the debugging screen for your reference.

Comment: On separate topic, don't use `var` - either `let` or `const`

Comment: @Gassanov any input on this query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55862940/how-to-load-an-html-inside-main-index-html-on-button-click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your response from API is object with data property, not just array with results

```
$.getJSON("/dashboard/", function(response, status)
        {
            chart.data.datasets[0].data = response.data;
            chart.update();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `test_data` is currently an object. You need to use

```
var test_data=data.data;
```

to access the array which is required.