# How to add some Html code which on another file in a div tag when I click a button using simple javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

#### page 1

```
     <html>
         <body>
            <h1>My heading</h1>
            <p>Some paragrap</p>
         </body>
     </html>
```

#### Page 2

```
  <html>
      <body>
         <button>Click</button>
         <div></div>
      </body>
   </html>
```

So when I click the button I want to that page 1 is shown on page 2 between div tag using simple javascript.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Try Free Code Camp for resources on how to get started with web development

Comment: You could have a look at this existing answer: [How to load an html inside main index html on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55863120/11700321). Alternatively, you could just use an `<a>` tag and redirect to the 2nd HTML page.

Comment: check here -> [how do i load an html page in a div using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17636528/how-do-i-load-an-html-page-in-a-div-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also add the following JavaScript code in a `<script>` tag just before your closing `</body>` tag, assuming your `<div>` tag on page2 has the `id="newpage"`.

```
function load(file) {

 document.getElementById("newpage").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="page1.html" ></object>';
}
```

you can then load this function by using `onclick` as follow:

```
onclick="load();";
```

Best of Luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can try `object` tag:

```
<html>
      <body>
         <button onclick="document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = '<object data='page1.html'></object>'">Click</button>
         <div></div>
      </body>
</html>
```

*while using object tag, note that duplicate `<html></html>` would not get added*